# From a text cell to a "real" php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have, on a mysql table, a column in which are stored through a print_r on a previous step of the program.

So I have on a text cell of the mysql db this value:

---

```
Array
(
    [id] => 129
    [group_id] => 9
    [rid] => 28
    [date] => 2014-02-09 10:00:00
    [real_time_start] => 00:00:00
    [real_time_end] => 00:00:00
    [site_id] => 1
    [sub_site_id] => 2
    [team1_id] => 9
    [team2_id] => 13
    [home] => 2
    [result_type] => 2
    [status] => 0
)
```

---

I have tried several ways, but with no success. How can I transform this one in a "real" php array?

Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Instead of using `print_r` use some proper serialization like php's built in mechanism (`serialize/unserialize`) or json (`json_encode/json_decode`). However, more solid solution would be to normalize your database, i.e. create table with those columns and add relationship to existing table. For further information about relationships read up on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database Despite that php's manual has direct solution: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore such data into readable PHP array do not use `print_r()` as its format is not easily readable by built-in parsers. You have several options:

- convert it to JSON using `json_encode()` and then decode through `json_decode`,
- convert to serialized format using `var_export()`, save to file and `require()` it,
- use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`, as Leri said,
- use YAML library (I recommend Symfony's one) and `Yaml::dump()` / `Yaml::parse()` your data.

Answer (score 0):

The `print_r()` function prints a variable in a human-readable format. Therefore, it has no reverse equivalent.

If you’re wanting to transform a representation of an array to a plain text version for storage and back again, then use something like PHP’s `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

To store an array to a table you should use ***serialize()*** function. When retrieving use ***unserialize()*** function to get the array back.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all

The suggestion of Jasper was great, I've been able to convert the "print_r" output in a "serialize" one using the function proposed.
Now I will use serialize/unserialize to solve this problem.